# Remove top 2 elements along with namespace using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an input XML as shown below

```
<ns9:Messages xmlns:ns9="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns9:Message1>
        <ZCOD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION02>
            <IDOC BEGIN="1">
                <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">                  
                    <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>                  
                    <MESTYP>COD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION</MESTYP>                   
                </EDI_DC40>
                <E101COD_S_SRV_CONF SEGMENT="1">
                    <REFOBJKEY>0000122425</REFOBJKEY>
                    <REFDOCTYPE>L2</REFDOCTYPE>                 
                </E101COD_S_SRV_CONF>
            </IDOC>
        </ZCOD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION02>
    </ns9:Message1>
</ns9:Messages>
```

I need the output to be as below, essentially removing the top 2 elements and the namespace. I am able to do it by applying 2 XSLT one after another, but how can I do it using one XSLT.
Please note I can not use template match on the 3rd level node (ZCOD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION02) as this name can be anything in runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <ZCOD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION02>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
     <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>
        <MESTYP>COD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION</MESTYP>
     </EDI_DC40>
     <E101COD_S_SRV_CONF SEGMENT="1">
        <REFOBJKEY>0000122425</REFOBJKEY>
        <REFDOCTYPE>L2</REFDOCTYPE>
    </E101COD_S_SRV_CONF>
 </IDOC>
</ZCOD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION02>
```

Best regards, Abinash

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes Micahel, it supports XSLT 3.0 Best regards, Abinash

Comment: Please remove the screenshots and replace them with text. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the name and namespace of your 2nd level node is fixed (*ns9:Message1*), you could apply the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns9="http://sap.com" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output exclude-result-prefixes="ns9" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="//*[parent::ns9:Message1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you,the issue is in the ouput the the namespace is still there.
 <ZCOD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION02 xmlns:ns1="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
         <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">     
     <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>     
     <MESTYP>COD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION</MESTYP>     
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E101COD_S_SRV_CONF SEGMENT="1">
     <REFOBJKEY>0000122425</REFOBJKEY>
     <REFDOCTYPE>L2</REFDOCTYPE>     
    </E101COD_S_SRV_CONF>
   </IDOC>
  </ZCOD_SERVICE_CONFIRMATION02>

Comment: @Abinash, I've edited the answer accordingly. In order to suppress the namespace definitions in the output, you can add _copy-namespaces="no"_ to the _copy-of_ node.